# How do I use jquery to append text to several divs when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When all 8 divs are clicked I want the remaining red divs to display well done. It doesn't appear to be working, I am trying to get class by using the hideous document.getElementsByClassName but I want something simpler that works. Please Help!

```
var score;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.b').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
});

function click() {
    score += 1;
    if (score === 8) {  document.getElementsByClassName(a).innerHTML += 'Well Done';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/BbSMW/8/ (JSFiddle)

Comment: You never execute the function `click()`. The method `$(...).click()` and your function are *not* the same.

Comment: Easiest way would be check if all the `b` class divs are hidden

Comment: unfortunately, implicit iteration doesn't happen with native javascript, it's something jquery implements. therefore, you will have to iterate over all of those elements and change the html one by one, unless you want to use jquery to do it(which can be done in one line very easily.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

-`score` was never given a default value, was resulting in `NaN` when trying to add 1 each time

-You never call `click()`

-You have to iterate over your div's and apply the `innerHTML` -- I just used jQuery since you already had it going for you:

```
var score = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.b').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        click();
    });
});

function click() {
    score += 1;
    if (score === 8) {  $(".a").text('Well Done');
    }
    console.log(score);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BbSMW/10/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to your code could be to check if any of the elements with class `b` are still visible:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.b').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            if($(".b:visible").length === 0) {//fading out element is still technically visible ;)
                $(".a").text("Well done");            
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Update to code to handle race condition mentioned in comments.

[**Updated Fiddle** (im dumb)](http://jsfiddle.net/BbSMW/14/)

Comment: doesn't seem to wait for all the blue ones to be hidden to say well done (after fixing typo)

Comment: there's a tiny race condition that happens if you click the last one before the previous one is completely hidden. solved by moving the if block into the fadeOut callback and testing for a length of 0

Comment: ya I was thinking about that too when I wrote it. Do you have an idea of how to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className").text("Well Done")
```

Put the above in your click handler.